# Can't make the bootstrap sprites work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-sprites

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm extremely new to bootstrap, and am having trouble making the glyphicons show up where I want them. I used the icon tag with the icon I wanted: `<i class="icon-home"></i>`. Besides the below code and adjusting the link in the .css file to where the image is saved, I haven't done anything. The whole element is:

```
<li class = "active">
    <a href="HomePage.html"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a>
</li>
```

I know I have the linking to the sprite image correct in my .css file, so that's not it. What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: Can I do that if the sprite I'm trying to get the image from is on my computer?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Thanks! Big help.

Comment: what did you? I'm having the same problems

Comment: Make sure the icons are accessable via http://<your.server.name>/<path_to_bootstrap>/img/glyphicons-halflings.png and loads in a browser. If this is not the case, you won't see the icons.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is:

```
<li class = "active">
    <i class="icon-home"></i<a href="HomePage.html">>Home</a>
</li>
```